# How can I use bootstrap and js properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

So I was wondering if there is a way to use javascript on top of Bootstrap 5 and I tried so but unfortunately, it doesn't work, so I was wondering what am I doing wrong?
Could it be that I'm doing the js wrong? Or is it something to do with bootstrap itself?

```js
var clicka = document.getElementById('colorClicker');
var bgchange = document.getElementById('showcasea');

clicka.addEventListener('click',() => {
bgchange.style.backgroundColor = red;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Elite\Desktop\bootstrap-travesy\css\style.css">
    <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!--!                               SHOWCASE                                             -->

<section id="showcasea" class="bg-dark text-light p-5 p-lg-0 pt-lg-5 text-center text-sm-start">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div>
                

                <h1>Become a <span class="text-warning">Web Developer</span> </h1>
                <p class="lead my-4">
                We focus on teaching our students the fundamentals of the latest
                and greatest technologies to prepare them for their first dev role!
                </p>
               


                <!--TODO:|USE JS HERE|-------->
<div class="container">

    <div 
    id="changeStuff" 
        
    class="            
                            d-flex 
                      flex-direction-row 
                      align-items-center 
                     justify-content-evenly
                            mr-5">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg m-r-20">Start The Enrollment</button>
    
        <a href="" id="colorClicker" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-circle">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icony" class = "bg-dark" width="2.5vh" height="2.5vh" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-code-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                <path d="M6.854 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L4.207 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zm2.292 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708L11.793 8l-2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0z"/>
              </svg></a>
        </div>    
</div>
        <!--TODO:|USE JS HERE|-------->
        
            </div>
            <img class="img-fluid w-50 d-none d-sm-block" src="img/showcase.svg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>


</section>
<!--!                             END OF SHOWCASE                                        -->
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="coolStuff.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind I added only the part I wanted to change because I would have to add too much code.

Comment: note that `red` should be a string data type like `"red"`, but this still didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So other than `red` needing to be `"red"` with quotes and `()` needing to be `function()`, your jscode is fine.  The issue occures with this class: `bg-dark` It seems bootstrap has this background color set to `!important` so its not able to be changed.  So what I recommend is to remove this class and style the background using CSS instead of bootstrap without the `!important` tag, then your jscode will work to change the background color.

See what I did here,  I changed the class `bg-dark` to something random like `bg-dark-temp` for `#showcasea`.  And now your jscode works (I also had to remove the empty href in `colorClicker` for your button to work).

Anyways take a look here:

```js
var clicka = document.getElementById('colorClicker');
var bgchange = document.getElementById('showcasea');

clicka.addEventListener("click", function() {
bgchange.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

```css
.bg-dark-temp {
  background-color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Elite\Desktop\bootstrap-travesy\css\style.css">
    <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!--!                               SHOWCASE                                             -->

<section id="showcasea" class="bg-dark-temp text-light p-5 p-lg-0 pt-lg-5 text-center text-sm-start">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div>
                

                <h1>Become a <span class="text-warning">Web Developer</span> </h1>
                <p class="lead my-4">
                We focus on teaching our students the fundamentals of the latest
                and greatest technologies to prepare them for their first dev role!
                </p>
               


                <!--TODO:|USE JS HERE|-------->
<div class="container">

    <div 
    id="changeStuff" 
        
    class="            
                            d-flex 
                      flex-direction-row 
                      align-items-center 
                     justify-content-evenly
                            mr-5">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg m-r-20">Start The Enrollment</button>
    
        <a id="colorClicker" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-circle">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="icony" class = "bg-dark" width="2.5vh" height="2.5vh" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-code-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                <path d="M6.854 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L4.207 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zm2.292 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708L11.793 8l-2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0z"/>
              </svg></a>
        </div>    
</div>
        <!--TODO:|USE JS HERE|-------->
        
            </div>
            <img class="img-fluid w-50 d-none d-sm-block" src="img/showcase.svg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>


</section>
<!--!                             END OF SHOWCASE                                        -->
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="coolStuff.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So yeah, I did what you said but now it just flashes in red whenever I click the button, it doesn't change it permanently to red. What could be the case?

Comment: And also I noticed it doesn't work every time I click it, more like one out of 5 times

Comment: I couldn't tell you without seeing more code. Could you post more code where the issue is replicable?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3dwe4nym/2/ here is a js fiddle link.  PS: Thank you very much for taking your time to help me, I appreciate it a lot!!!

Comment: You need to remove `href=""` from this line: `<a href="" id="colorClicker" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-circle">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bgchange.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: have you tested it? cuz i tested it and it doesnt work